# Using Spring Data MongoDB to find and update document using compound _id field

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, bson

I have a custom key class in my project as below.

I have implemented Serializable, implemented hashCode and equals too.

```
public class SalesKey implements Serializable {

    Date timestamp;
    String hostName;

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp=timestamp;
    }

    public void setHostName(String hostName) {
        this.hostName=hostName;
    }

    public String getHostName() {
        return hostName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    ..
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    ...
    }

}
```

I use the custom key class in my MongoDB Document class as below.

```
@Document(collection = "Sales")
public class Sales {

    @Id
    SalesKey salesKey;

    //Other fields
}
```

I am able to save the documents into mongodb using spring data mongodb.

```
Sales sales=new Sales();

SalesKey salesKey=getSalesKey();

sales.setSalesKey(salesKey)

//set other fields for sales object

//Save sales Document object to mongodb
```

The Save is successful.

I am also able to fetch by using the below query in my SalesRepository interface which extends MongoRepository.
After constructing, the salesKey as before.

```
@Query(value = "{ '_id' : ?0 }")
public Sales filterBySalesKey(SalesKey salesKey);
```

When I try to update using a criteria API as below, for updating specific fields in the document.

I first use the Criteria as below.

```
Criteria salesKeyCriteria = Criteria.where("_id").is(salesKey);
```

With the above criteria I then execute a update statment,

But, my update fails with the error,

**org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.demo.model.SalesKey**

I am using Spring Data MongoDB framework and MongoDB 3.2.1.

Can anyone help me what is the codec and how can I add one to make my update successful.

Comment: can you show us the actual update statement ?

Comment: Please add the update statement + the json extract from mongo for one of your Sales document.

Answer (score 0):

Since `SalesKey` is your Mongo `_id`, you could do the following with MongoTemplate:

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
...
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(salesKey));
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query,Update.update("field", "new-value"),Sales.class);
```

**Following up on your comment on mongo explain**

If I look at the update explain in mongo shell:

```
$ db.sales.explain().update({"_id" : { "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-25T12:12:59.251Z"), "hostName" : "myhostname" }},{value:"new-value"})
```

It shows me the winning plan using IDHACK:

```
"winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "UPDATE",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IDHACK"
            }
        },
```

Example of a Sales document:

```
{ "_id" : { "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-25T12:12:59.251Z"), "hostName" : "value" }, "value" : "new" }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I can use findOne method. But, I want to update a few fields in the collection and do not want the entire document to be fetched , updated and then persisted to db again. I want the find to be used as part of update call which will do in-place changes.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I am trying to do update by finding. But, it is failing with the codec error.    If I try to pass the individual fields in my salesKey object as separate conditions instead of directly using my custom class it works, not sure why it would.    And another thing, I just saw with explain() function in mongo shell , using when using _id field in this way with a custom class, the index on the _id field is not being used.  Not sure why collection scan was used and not index.

Comment: I copied your SalesKey and the code above works for me. Could you still post your actual update statement ?

Comment: about the explain, I tried on my side and it seems to be doing ok. Updated the answer to show you what I see on my side.

Comment: Not sure what was the issue.was .It worked without the codec issue now.  I have shared the code I used in this repo , https://github.com/bsridhar77/sales/blob/master/src/main/java/com/demo/app/repository/SalesTemplateImpl.java.

Comment: I am not able to use part of the _id field in my query. Also, I am not able to use the timestamp field alone for date operations like $gte and $lte. Maybe I will raise a separate issue for that.